# Simplified equations for FM (frequency modulation) synthesis and PM (phase modulation)?

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation

Clicking on the links I find on the web it seems many authors don't express them
neatly enough for me or they're even confusing the two. Can someone please clear this up?

Is frequency modulation

\begin{align}
&\rm  \sin((frequency+modulator)time-phase)\\
&\qquad\quad\textrm{or is it}\\ 
& \rm  \sin(frequency*time+modulator-phase)\quad ? 
\end{align}

Ugh!

Comment: Why 'carrier='? The carrier should be without modulation!

Comment: @N74 Fixed and done. I think you can edit questions if you have enough points.

Comment: $x(t) = A(t) e^{i \phi(t)}$ : $A(t)$ is the time-varying amplitude, $\phi(t)$ the phase, $\omega(t) = \phi'(t)$ the time-varying (angular) frequency. for $x(t)$ to be a pitched sound, $A(t)$ has to be band-limited, and $\frac{\omega'(t)}{\omega(t)}$ too

Comment: @user1952009 Am I 100% correct in assuming $phase modulation=sin(frequency*time-(phase+modulator))$. Can I check that off the list?

Comment: @user1952009 I also noticed $sin((frequency+modulator)time-phase))$ will have modulation increasing in proportion to time. The superficial solution $sin((frequency+\frac{modulator}{time})time-phase))$ gives $sin((frequency*time+modulator-phase))$, phase modulation!? So let me take a careful look at what you just said...

Comment: David Austin wrote an article on that: http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-synthesizer

Comment: to be clear, AM is when the signal is in $A(t)$ and $w(t)$ is constant, and $FM$ is when the signal is in $\omega'(t) / \omega(t)$, and $A(t)$ is constant. phase modulation is almost the same as FM but high-pass filtered, with the signal in $\phi(t)$. AM is the most obvious way for transmitting a signal, while FM is the most robust for the radio when there are some interferances

Comment: @WillieWong Can't you just move it there?

Comment: **I** certainly can't. But if you agree I'll flag a moderator to do so.

Comment: @WillieWong Ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $t$ is time, $s(t)$ is the (appropriately scaled) signal, $\omega_0$ is the angular frequency, and $\phi_0$ is a phase offset, then **phase modulation** is
$$ t \mapsto \sin(\omega_0 t + \phi_0 + s(t)) $$
Different signs for $s(t)$ and/or $\phi_0$ may be used, depending on conventions and context.

**Frequency modulation** is more complex to write down, because we want $s(t)$ to vary the *derivative* of the argument to the sine as a function of time. We get something like:
$$ t \mapsto \sin\bigl(\phi_0 + {\textstyle\int_0^t(\omega_0+s(u))du} \bigr) $$
which is the same as
$$ t \mapsto \sin\bigl(\omega_0t + \phi_0 + {\textstyle\int_0^t s(u)du} \bigr) $$

We see that phase modulation is the same as frequency modulation by the *derivative* of the signal -- which looks like a boost of high frequencies and attenuation of low frequencies.

---

Your proposed
$$ t \mapsto \sin\bigl( (\omega_0+s(t))t + \phi_0 \bigr) $$
won't work -- it would look like phase modulation, with a modulation strength that *increases monotonically* and without bound depending on how long it is since $t=0$.

Comment: How would you plot carrier sin(t) with frequency modulator that's also a sine function here https://www.desmos.com/calculator?